# Отправляются не корректные данные через json

Tags: php, laravel

Если я с помощью `dd($event->get())` получаю данные, то выводятся корректные данные

```
  $language = app()->getLocale();
  $event = Event::join('event_translations', 'events.id', '=', 'event_translations.event_id')
            ->where('event_translations.locale', '=', $language);

  dd($event->get());
```

А если с помощью **json**, то нет

```
    return response()
        ->json([
            'model' => $event->get(),
        ]);
```

Например,

**dd($event->get())**

```
attributes: array:8 [
"id" => 27
"picture" => "cutlery.png"
"created_at" => "2017-01-19 14:24:18"
"updated_at" => "2017-01-19 14:24:18"
"event_id" => 3
"locale" => "pl"
"name" => "RESTAURACJI"
"description" => "RESTAURACJI\r\n"]
```

**json**

```
created_at:"2017-01-19 14:24:18"
description:"BARMANI NA ZLECZENIE"
event_id:3
id:27
locale:"pl"
name:"BARMANI NA ZLECZENIE"
picture:"cutlery.png"
updated_at:"2017-01-19 14:24:18"
```

Для локализации использую пакет dimsav/laravel-translatable

Laravel 5.3

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что неверные `description` и `name`?

Comment: @NPreston, да, именно они

Comment: Скорее всего в `attributes` хранятся "оригинальные" данные, а при формировании json, некоторые атрибуты преобразуются в методах класса `Event`, таких как `getNameAttribute()` и `getDescriptionAttribute()`. Они у вас имеются?